# Debug external project from winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two separated projects
XLSWriterUI (WinFormApp)
XLSWriter (consoleapp)

The XLSWriteUI starts without any problems. In the XLSWriteUI applications, there Is a button called "Parse". When you hit this button, the XLSWriter application executable Is called like this:

Main.cs In XLSWriterUI

```
 private void Parse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Enable waitcursor
            // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            Tabs_SetWaitCursor(Parse);

            try
            {
                Debug.Text = String.Empty;
                Debug.Refresh();

                // Create process
                // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                // Set startup parameters
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"XLSWriter.exe";
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = Tabs_GetParameters();
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(StdOutReceiver);

                // Start process
                // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                proc.Start();
                proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
                proc.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                // Whatever
                Debug.AppendText(Ex.Message);
            }
            // Cancel waitcursor
            // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            Tabs_CancelWaitCursor(Parse);
        }
```

As you can see, the executable of the XLSWriter Is called when you hit the Parse-button. I don't want this. I want to be able to debug the XLSWriter application project when you hit the button so I can step in and out in code in Visual studio.

So basically, I want to do this:
Start both the applications via visual studio so they are running, 
Set a breakpoint in XLSWriter, 
When I click on the button in XLSWriterUI, the breakpoint In XLSWriter should be triggerd.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just use the debug tab in the properties if XLSWriter with the parameters you're passing? Is there a reason you **need** to also have the UI app running at the same time?

Comment: if XLSWriter is something you wrote you could you not invoke it by making it a reference of this? so you can call the class and start the writer? then you would debug it as it went, rather than just spawning a process which happens to be an exe you wrote

Answer (score 0):

If you have both proejcts in your solution then From Solution Use Set Startup projects feature and choose your project from multiple startup options

Comment: No, they are not in the same solution.

Comment: Then simply attach the process of the other project. Isn't it better that you include that project in your solution temporarily?

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010:
Open solution for XLSWriter
ctrl+alt+p 
attach to process.

You need to set a period of sleep time at the beginning in order to make room for attaching the running process.